# Pkg_config can't find file I have, changing path didn't work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, path, ubuntu-18.04

I'm installing a theme on my Ubuntu and when I run:

```
$ sudo ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
```

I get the error:

```
No package 'gdk-pixbuf-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.
```

I have the gdk-pixbuf-2.0 folder in `usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`
so I did the command:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
```

and tried installing it again. It still couldn't find the gdk-pixbuf-2.0. Any idea on how I can change the path to find the folder? Also, this last part might be irrelevant but how would I then remove that path after I set it without damaging the default paths?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev` package installed; `-dev` packages are the ones that ship, among other things, pkg-config support files.

I don't think you'll need to change `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` once you have the right dependency installed.